# Prepopulate form with first step post method

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a two part form the first step is on the home page and I want the fields someone would enter to populate to the next step.

I have tried adding an action attribute to the form tag so that each form field can populate it. The form is getting the information via a post method

Next Step

I just want the first name and zip to auto populate when they hit the next step button on the new page.

First step form in header of this page: preview9.mymosierdatasite.com/

needs to fill out First name field and zip field in http://preview9.mymosierdatasite.com/instant-results/

Answer (score 0):

On the second form, name the text inputs you need to bring over the same as on the first form (for example 'zip'). This  will populate the 'zip' field of the second form with whatever has been input to the 'zip' field on the first form. Note: This is just an example, you should validate and sanitise the contents of `$_POST` before using it.

```
<input type="text" name="zip" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['zip']) ? $_POST['zip'] : ''; ?>">
```